# Dos2unix in Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

Can you please let me know the steps that needs to be followed to install Dos2unix utility in fedora 13.

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 8):

not having used fedora13 personally, does typing "yum install dos2unix" not work?

Comment: will verify and come back to you..

Comment: It works for me in Fedora 17.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below and achieve the same effect:

```
tr -d '\r' < input_file  > output_file
```